# How to order by file size and delete if size is zero

Tags: bash, shell

How do I write a script that will list all files in a user-defined directory, as well as all sub-directories and order them by size? As well as give the user the option to delete any file that is a size of 0.

The script I have so far lists all files in *current* directory as well as sub-directories

```
for file in $( find . -type f ${dir} );
    do
    echo "$(basename "$file")"
done
```

Comment: See [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), and [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: ...that said, you're asking a **lot** of different things here -- perhaps you should split it into separate questions. Some of them (like how to let the user define arguments to your script, and how to sort find results, and how to prompt for options) are already answered elsewhere on the site.